# Issues installing psycopg2 inside virtualenv Python 3.4 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4, psycopg2, virtualenvwrapper

```
(my_env)user@web:~/myproject$ pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
```

I have setuptools installed...I have never seen this error before while installing psycopg2

Comment: With `(my_env)` active, do you see `setuptools` when you run `pip list`?

Comment: Yes 
setuptools (18.2)

Comment: IT fix: delete then recreate the virtual env?

Comment: IT fix worked...can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and fixed installing python 3 dev:

```
$sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```